# Header image on paypal payment page returning 404 intermittently

Tags: paypal, symlink

I have added a header image to customize the paypal payment page for my site eatingAtkins.ie/products.

When you go to the payment page (by clicking link in cart) sometimes the header image is there and sometimes it's not - I'm seeing it broken in Safari in Windows most often. I can see a 404 error in the console. However if I inspect the url being used in web developer tools it is correct. The url for the image is https://eatingatkins.ie/wp-content/uploads/site_images/ea_head.gif Opening that by itself always works.

I recently set up SSL for the site and the hosting company set up a symlink so that https://eatingatkins.ie/anything will show the resource in the http directory. Could this cause an issue with this header image? Does it need to be in the https folder directly and not through using a symlink.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas why this image is returning a 404. It is happening everytime for me now. But it does show the image when you paste the url directly into a browser.

After speaking to support from my hosting company I don't think its related to the fact that I'm using a symlink instead of a direct link..

Answer (score 0):

I asked the hosting company to remove the symlink and put the image file in a directory in the https folder and it loads the image on the payment page every time.